# How to call bxslider.js in a custom module?

Tags: magento2

I have a custom module, I need to call a library of sliders there, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            bxslider: 'Vendor_module/js/bxslider',
        }
    }
};
```

> 2. app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/bxslider.js

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       //The bxslider content lib here
});
```

> 3. app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/file.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'bxslider'], function($, bxslider) {
    });
    //slider code here
</script>
```

**Don't forget to :**

- `clean the cache`
- `clean var/view_preprocessed content`
- `clean pub/static content`
- `deploy the static content : php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`